# Symfony: sfError404Exception: This request has been forwarded to a 404 error page by the action

Tags: php, debugging, redirect, symfony1, http-status-code-404

When building a website in Symfony 1.3 my development server refuses to display my custom 404 page.

I have left the config settings as standard, so my error module is the default, as can be seen in my debug toolbar:

```
sf_error_404_action: error404
sf_error_404_module: default
```

This request has been forwarded to a 404 error page by the action "article/edit".

**Why is my custom 404 page not shown?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that this is actually the default behaviour when debug is turned on.

Turn off debugging if you want to see the actual '404' error page.

**index.php: Symfony shows the symfony error page**

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', true);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```

**index.php: Symfony shows the custom 404 error page**

```
$configuration = ProjectConfiguration::getApplicationConfiguration('frontend', 'dev', false);
sfContext::createInstance($configuration)->dispatch();
```